# Not Able to Find SCCM MPcontrol log location in Site Server

Tags: software-distribution, sccm, system-center

I am not able find the mpcontrol.log in one of site server.

Searched in location E:\SMS_CCM\Logs ,but failed get the log.Actually What is the purpose of the folder SMS_CCM?

[Please check below screenshots]

From which drive and which folder i can get the log.

Comment: [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/0wAEJ.png
  [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/BiXbw.png
  [3]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/DGXg3.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check E:\SMS\Logs.

Note that the mpcontrol.log file will only exist on your management point, not your distribution points (not sure if they're one and the same in your infrastructure, just going by the info provided)

Comment: Yes you are correct.In this server  MP role is not  installed.This is a Distribution point.Thank you. Also i am checking logs in  rite location for logs? E:\SMS_CCM\Logs.What is the purpose of the folder SMS_CCM?

Comment: If I remember correctly, the SMS_CCM folder is created when the management point role is installed (if the client isn't already present). So I'm guessing it was installed at some point on this server but has since been removed.